# SQL Query works from Access but not from R using RJDBC package

Tags: r, ms-access, jdbc

I have been all day trying to solve this problem..
I have an Access Database and I want to UPDATE some data from R using JDBC connection.
The UPDATE query works perfectly if I execute it from SQL Query editor in Access, but is not working from R and I dont know why. This is my code:

```
library(devtools)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

setwd("mypath")

access_driver_file_name <- "Access_JDBC42.jar"
access_driver_class <- "com.hxtt.sql.access.AccessDriver"
access_data_file <- "my_database.accdb"    #poner aqui el nombre de la base 1
access_jdbc_url <- paste("jdbc:access:/", getwd(), "\\", access_data_file, sep="") 
access_jdbc_driver <- JDBC(driverClass=access_driver_class, classPath=paste(getwd(), "\\", access_driver_file_name, sep=""))

con <- dbConnect(access_jdbc_driver, access_jdbc_url)
dbListTables(con)#this work perfectly

dbSendUpdate(con, 'UPDATE TableName SET TableName.Field = "Casa"
WHERE (([TableName].[Field]="Oficina"));')
```

`If I copy UPDATE TableName SET TableName.Field = "Casa" WHERE (([TableName].[Field]="Oficina")); and paste it in Access the query works, but R returns:`

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate
  JDBC ERROR: Syntax error:  Stopped parse at .(id21)
  Statement: UPDATE TableName SET TableName.Field = "Casa"
WHERE (([TableName].[Field]="Oficina"));
```

I tried the same with dbSendQuery and with dbGetQuery and I get always the same error.
Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance!

I tried the same with dbSendQuery and with dbGetQuery and I get always the same error.

Comment: Several DBMSes (iirc) require single-quotes for string literals and double-quotes for identifiers (column names). For instance, perhaps `"UPDATE TableName SET TableName.Field = 'Casa' WHERE (([TableName].[Field]='Oficina'))"`

Comment: Since this query does not return anything, so you should be using either `res <- dbSendStatement(..)` (and a subsequent call to `dbClearResult(res)`) or just `res <- dbExecute(..)` (no need to clear).

Comment: Thank you very much but nothing works, I changued the quotes and I tried using dbSendStatement and dbExecute too but R still returning the same error:
Error in dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: Syntax error:  Stopped parse at .(id21)

Comment: I connect to accdb with odbc like this with no issues: `DBI::dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/path/to/my.accdb;"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution.
I change the package to connect with Access.
Now I using RODBC package. First I need to install ODBC driver to Access, and after I run this code and execute my UPDATE query without problem:

```
require(RODBC)
channel=odbcConnectAccess2007("my_path/my_data_base.accdb")
sqlQuery(channel, "UPDATE Table_Name SET Table_Name.column = 'Casa'
WHERE (([Table_Name].[Column]='Oficina'));")
odbcClose(channel) #this is to desconect the DB
```